# Prevent LWC from being unloaded

Tags: lightning-web-components

This is not about using the standard `unload`, `beforeUnload` or `visibilitychange` change events.

What I want to do is something like this:

```
disconnectedCallback() {
    let allValid = this.getInputStates();

    if(!allValid){
        //prevent Component from being unloaded
    }
}

getInputStates() {
    let allInputs = Array.from(this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input'));

        for(const i of inputs){
            if(!i. checkValidity()) {
                return false;
            }
        }

    return true;
}
```

However, in `disconnectedCallback()` I don't have access to any event to do a `preventDefault()`.

Is there any way to accomplish what I am looking for?

Answer (score 1):

The `disconnectedCallback` event is not cancelable--the component has already been unloaded, and you're being advised to clean up any resources that are no longer used as a result. It's too late at that point to cancel the unload process. However, in Salesforce, you can use [`lightning:unsavedChanges`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:unsavedChanges/documentation) to provide a chance to prevent navigation in Salesforce before losing data.

Comment: Appreciate that @sfdcfox